# How to cancel an optimistic lock in a spring boot hibernate

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, transactions

The project has @Entity1 which has relationship OneToMany of @Entity2. Also @Entity1 has a relationship ManyToOne to @Entity3.
I have a @Controller that adds data to the database for @Entity2, while also updating the date field of the associated @Entity3, but it is not necessary to specify an absolutely exact date there.
In my case, two @Entity1 objects have a reference to the same related @Entity3.
When parallel requests from two clients are executed, the server returns an OptimisticLockException to one and rolls back the entire transaction, which must necessarily save @Entity2.
Please tell me how can I cancel the OptimisticLockException exception in spring boot hibernate only for @Entity3?

I have tried to isolate saving the associated entity field @Entity3 separately from the external transaction using
`@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.NOT_SUPPORTED)`
but as a result, many tests stopped working in the project because of this)

Answer (score 0):

As a result, I used direct sql queries to update with the javax.persistence field.EntityManager instead of the hibernate Entity method. Thanks to this OptimisticLock is no longer thrown away and the field is updated.